# I learned the high order function recently. I tried to write some codes using high order function but I got stucked

Tags: python

Write a function that takes in a number and determines if the digits contain two adjacent `8`s.

```
def double_eights(n):
    """Return true if n has two eights in a row.
    >>> double_eights(8)
    False
    >>> double_eights(88)
    True
    >>> double_eights(2882)
    True
    >>> double_eights(880088)
    True
    >>> double_eights(12345)
    False
    >>> double_eights(80808080)
    False
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
```

I tried to call `double_eights` by passing `n//10` as an argument. 
I kept encountering errors when `2882` was passed in as an argument. The double eights function returned nothing when that argument was passed in. I attached what I've tried so far.

```
    if n < 10:
        return False
    elif (n % 10 == 8) and ((n // 10) % 10 == n % 10):
        return True
    double_eights(n //10)
```

Doctests for double_eights

```
>>> from lab01_extra import *
>>> double_eights(8)
False
>>> double_eights(88)
True
>>> double_eights(2882)

# Error: expected
#     True
# but got
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with higher order functions. Did you mean *recursive* functions? (The two concepts have no relation really, although both are widely used in functional programming.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes, I mean recursive functinos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return` that last recursive call, otherwise `None` will be returned by default on inputs that don't satisfy the conditions of the `if` and `elif` statements:

```
def double_eights(n):
    if n < 10:
        return False
    elif (n % 10 == 8) and ((n // 10) % 10 == 8):  #  8 instead of n % 10
        return True
    return double_eights(n // 10)

                                #  Output:
print(double_eights(8))         #  False
print(double_eights(88))        #  True
print(double_eights(2882))      #  True
print(double_eights(880088))    #  True
print(double_eights(12345))     #  False
print(double_eights(80808080))  #  False
```

The `8 instead of n % 10` is there because the `and` evaluates the second term only if the first one is `True` (in which case you know that `n % 10 == 8` so why re-calculate it?).

---

*note*: `double_eights` is not a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), but it is a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful!